# Startup script Problem

Tags: bash, scripts

I am new to Ubuntu.I want to run this script every time my system reboots.Is there a way to do that?Thanks in advance for help.

```
# !/bin/bash
#fix resolution problem
xrandr --newmode "1440x900_60.00"  106.50  1440 1528 1672 1904  900 903 909 934  -   hsync +vsync   
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1440x900_60.00
```

Comment: Did you try with "Startup Applications"?

Comment: Yes,tried with 'startup applications'. Didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all make your file executable by using this command :

```
chmod +x file_name
```

after you go to the file location

then add this line to

```
/etc/rc.local
```

here is the line:

```
/path/to/file/file_name
```

next time you restart your PC i think it will work well.

Answer (score 0):

### To execute a script upon reboot:

1. Put your script in **`/etc/rc0.d`**
2. Make it executable: `sudo chmod +x K99_script`
3. Notes:

   - The scripts in this directory are executed in alphabetical order.
   - The name of your script must begin with **`K99`** to run at the right time.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a cron job using the special string `@reboot`.

Make sure your script is executable.

Run `crontab -e` (if it requires sudo privleges use `sudo crontab -e` to edit root's crontab)

Your crontab command should look like: `@reboot   /path/to/script.sh`