# Running Bash script at login

Tags: bash, login, scripts, startup, cron

This question has been asked numerous times but for some reason, none of the solutions proposed worked for me. I just want to run a simple script after the user has logged in.

**Here are my attempts:**

- I have tried putting the script in `/etc/init.d/` and making a symlink in `/etc/rc0.d`.
- I tried scheduling it using the `@reboot` in crontab (`crontab -e`). Annoyingly, `@reboot` does not seem to work in Ubuntu(?). I tried this simple line`@reboot echo "hi there"` to no avail.
- I tried putting it into the root's crontab(`sudo crontab -e`) but still nothing happened. Also a simple `echo` in this crontab does not work too.
- I also tried to use the @reboot syntax suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335615/does-ubuntu-support-reboot-in-crontab) (`@reboot root /home/me/Desktop/script.sh`)
- Followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453851/startup-script-problem) and placed the path of the script in /etc/rc.local

**Notes:**

- I'm using Ubuntu 14.04
- home is mounted, but I also tried my attempts in a VM where home is not mounted
- I only want to run the script after the user has logged in
- Nothing fancy about the script it just echoes "hello world"

Comment: Do you need to run it at a specific runlevel? Do you need to run it in a terminal?

Comment: @kos I guess not, it's just a simple attempt of running a script at startup, it only contains an `echo`

Comment: I guess you want a terminal to see the output of the script, that's the only problem; the only hack I've ever managed to come up with (at least using `gnome-terminal` or `mate-terminal`) is [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/622442/open-terminal-at-startup-and-run-java-application/622500#622500); change `mate-terminal` to `gnome-terminal` and remove `sudo -H`, and obviously change the chain of commands to just `echo hello world`

Comment: If you don't need to output to a TTY there are way nicer solution; probably at least some of the methods you've tried worked already, you just couldn't catch the output since the script is not run in a terminal.

Comment: if I use `notify-send` instead will it send a notification? This way terminal output is not needed

Comment: Yes, given that you use it at the correct runlevel (in this case you want `X` to be running already, so you could use the Startup Applications method to run a script containing the `notify-send` command, that way you could also add in other commands).

Comment: can you point out what method I can use to run a script that does a `notify-send`? I'm using Unity as my DE

Comment: Not on Ubuntu right now, however `notify-send 'hello world'` should be enough; create a text file named, say, `script.sh`, say, in `~/`; then add a shebang to the start of the file (`#!/bin/bash`) and the command on the next line; mark the script as executable by running `chmod +x ~/script.sh` and add an entry to Startup Applications to call it; the command would be simply the path to the script, i.e. `~/script.sh`

Comment: @kos that works, thanks. Add that as answer so I can accept. Anyway, I'm still curious why all other methods does not work (using crontab, using init.d, etc.)

Comment: I would, but as it stands it wouldn't really answer the question; maybe you can rephrase the question asking for how to run a `notify-send` command at startup? Beside that, the methods you already tried probably worked, although none of those methods are meant to output to a terminal; let's pick the first method (`/etc/init.d/`); that's usually used to start daemons, and those scripts are usually run way before `X` is actually running; an easy way to check an `/etc/init.d/` script's output would be, for example, to redirect the output to a file.

Comment: Have you tried putting what you need inside the `~/.login` file?

Answer (score 4):

The standard location for a script that must run at `login` is `/etc/profile`. It will then run for every user (once) when they log in. The user never gets to see the output of the script, it is logged

If it is only for a specific user, it should be added to `.profile` in their home directory.

With `login` I mean when you enter your username and password.

Any errors normally show up in `~/.xsession-errors`

If it has to run every time you open a terminal window, it should be added to `/etc/bash.bashrc` or to `.bashrc` in the user's home directory.

At work, I mount a number of network shares when I log in. This is done in `.profile` in my home directory (it needs only to be done once).

Every time I open a terminal window I get a [fortune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune_%28Unix%29) cookie. This happens because the last line in `.bashrc` in my home directory contains `fortune`.